# After updating chaincode,i lost the init data before

Tags: hyperledger

every time i change the chaincode and do the deploy, it return a new chaincodeID and i have to do init again, but in production environment, we can not do this,we just want to update the chaincode and the history data must be keeped. i seached, https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-22 this url tells me now hyperledger not support for chaincode upgrade, so what can i do if i need this now? if i misunderstand it, you can tell me. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you found in FAB-22, Fabric v0.5-0.6 has no support for chaincode “upgrade”. The reason for such behavior is how Fabric saves information in the ledger. 
When chaincode tries to call PutState method:

```
PutState(customKey string, value []byte) error
```

Fabric will automatically add ChaincodeId to the key and save provided “value” using name `CHAINCODE_ID + customKey`. 
As a result each chaincode has an access only to its own variables. After update, chaincode receives new ChaincodeId and new visibility area.

We found several workarounds for how to deal with this limitation.

**Custom upgrade feature**:

1. In your chaincode (v1) you can create function “readAllVars” which loads all variables from ledger using “stub.RangeQueryState” method.
2. When new version(v2) is deployed, you can make cross-chaincode request to (v1) using “InvokeChaincode”  and read previous state from “readAllVars”, then save everything in (v2) area of visibility.

**DAO layer**:

You can create separate chaincode which will be responsible “read/write” operations. All versions will use this DAO as a proxy for all “PutState” and “GetState” requests. With such approach all Chaincode’s versions will work in the same area of visibility. At the same time this DAO layer become responsible for security and should guarantee that no other chaincodes have access to private information.

Comment: thank you, i try this and see the result of v1, so i think this is ok.